# Capture SMS Response in a Data Extension without sending a Next Message

Tags: journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms

I want to use Journey Builder to send an SMS. If someone responds to the SMS, I want to capture their response in a data extension and have that trigger a task in SalesCloud. Additionally, I do NOT want to send a next message acknowledging the consumer' response.

Example: We send an SMS via journey builder. A consumer responds. No matter what the response is form consumer, we want to capture it and not send a next response. Instead the consumer's response will trigger a task creation in SalesCloud and send to SalesCloud for an agent to handle.

Initial message varies, as it is dynamic based on personalization.

Data Extension Sent from name: Test for Capture Response
Data extension where responses will live: SMS Responses

I assume this will require ampscript but each time I try, I receive an error response and NO response is sent to DE. Ampscript I am using below: (using pay as initial response from consumer but want this to be ANY response)

```
%%[
var @response, @validResponse
set @response = [MSG(0).NOUNS]

if IndexOf(@response,'pay')>0 or IndexOf(@response,'no')>0 then
  set @validResponse = true
endif

if @validResponse == true then

   UpsertData('SMS Responses', 1, 'MobileNumber', MOBILE_NUMBER, 'Response', @response)

]%%
Thank you for responding!
%%[ else ]%%
Your response is invalid. Please reply 'yes' or 'no'.
%%[ endif ]%%
```